# Random numbers in array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, random

I need to fill an array A with 5 random numbers from a possible 50. Duplicates are allowed. I then need to fill the same array a second time but with unique numbers that did not appear in the first or second filling of the array. I am using the code below to generate the array the second time. I am stuck on how to search the first array for duplicates at the same time. Any help appreciated! Thanks

```
boolean drawn;
    for (int i=0; i<A.length; i++) {
            do {
                    drawn = false;
                    A[i] = 1 + (int)(Math.random() * 50);


                    for (int j=0; j<i; j++)
                            if (A[i] == A[j]) 
                                drawn = true;                                                                               

            } while (drawn);
```

Comment: I'd draw the logic on paper. You can use if-then logic, though  I think there are many ways to skin this cat

Comment: If you used a `List` instead of an array, you could leverage the [contains()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29) method.

Answer (score 1):

Use a List<> to keep track of all allowed numbers, and as you use them, remove them from the list.   Then, for your 'second pass', instead of always getting a random number * 50, get a random number * list size().  Then the actual number you use is list.get(location) instead of just number.

(your list will start out as 1,2,3,4,5, but then when 3 is used, the list will become 1,2,4,5, ..., So that when you get the next "random()" number of 3, that is actually a 4.)

Answer (score 1):

I would do this:

```
List<Integer> choices = new ArrayList<Integer>();  
Random r = new Random();
for(int i = 0; i <N;i++)
{  
    choices.add(r.nextInt(N-1)+1;
}    
Set<Integer> uniques = new HashSet<Integer>();  
Collections.shuffle(uniques);  
//remove first 5 entries from uniques 
//repeat for second pass
```

This of course has the possibility (as minimal as it is) that there will be a set remaining of less than size 5.

Answer (score 0):

Store your 50 random number candidates in an array `random` of size `50`

Keep a counter initially set to `random.length`.So, here`counter` will be initialized to 49.

Then Generate a number `r` from `0` to `counter-1` and choose `random[r]` as your number.

Now go ahead and swap `random[r]` with `random[counter-1]`. Decrement `counter` so that next time you will only be searching the first 49 elements of the array, and continue this process whenever you pick a number.

Now simply If you want a number that you have not chosen before, generate `r` from `0` to `counter-1` so that `random[r]` comes from the unique elements in the array which will be in the beginning.

```
    int[] randoms= new int[50];
     .
     .  //populate your array with the candidate numbers
     .
    int counter= randoms.length;
    Random rand = new Random();

    public int getUnique(){
      //Get a random number in the range 0 to counter-1
      int r = rand.nextInt(counter);
      int myElement = randoms[r];
      randoms[r] = randoms[counter-1];
      randoms[counter-1]= myElement;
      counter--;
      return myElement; 
    }
```

And whenever you want to allow duplicates, generate an `r` from `0` to `random.length -1` and choose `random[r]` as your number. Notice that we still have to keep track of the numbers used so that `getUnique()` still works:

```
    public int getAny(){
      //Get a random number in the range 0 to random.length-1
      int r = rand.nextInt(random.length);
      int myElement = randoms[r];
      if(r < counter){
        randoms[r] = randoms[counter-1];
        randoms[counter-1]= myElement;
        counter--;
      }
      return myElement; 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a list containing your 50 numbers, and use a Random to get 5 indices between 0 and 50, to create your first random array.

For the second pass, create a copy of the first list, but remove the numbers that are in the first random array. Then shuffle this second list (using `Collections.shuffle()`), and take the 5 first elements.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use one extra array each time you want to fill the array as you need to store the previous array elements. Something like:

```
boolean drawn;
System.arraycopy( A, 0, B, 0, A.length );
for (int i=0; i<A.length; i++) {
        do {
                drawn = false;
                A[i] = 1 + (int)(Math.random() * 50);

                for (int j=0; j<A.length; j++)
                        if (A[i] == B[j]) 
                            drawn = true; 

                for (int j=0; j<i; j++)
                        if (A[i] == A[j]) 
                            drawn = true;                                                                               

        } while (drawn);
```

`

Comment: @user1930614.. Don't just copy the code. Try to understand what exactly is happening. That will help you in long run.